# <textarea> causing 404 error on particular inputs

Tags: html, textarea

I've come across a weird problem. I have a simple form which submits data to a php processor page. However, the following input to the description field causes a 404 Error.

> To recognize and reward the best in
>   Indian theatre, The Mahindra and
>   Mahindra presents META (Mahindra
>   Excellence in Theatre Awards). The
>   only award of its kind, META is
>   designed to showcase the best in
>   theatre being produced in India. An
>   eminent selection committee shortlists
>   the 10 best plays from innumerable
>   entries from all across India. These
>   plays are staged and adjudged under 13
>   award categories. The festival
>   culminates with an scintillating
>   awards ceremnony. Entering its sixth
>   year, META’s objective remains to
>   encourage all aspects of theatre craft
>   such as playwriting, set, costume and
>   light design, direction and
>   performance and promoting theatre.

I've tried changing the apostrophes and commas, even the brackets, but it didn't help.
The code for the form:

```
<form class="cms" action="add.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                                <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text">
                        Title
                    </td>
                    <td class="input">
                        <input type="text" size="20" name="title" value="" />
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text">
                        Date
                    </td>
                    <td class="input">
                        <input type="text" size="20" name="date" value="" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="text">
                        Image
                    </td>
                    <td class="input">
                                                <input type="file" name="image" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td class="text">
                        Description
                    </td>
                    <td class="input">
                        <textarea name="description" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text">

                        Link
                    </td>
                    <td class="input">
                        <input type="text" size="20" name="link" value="" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text">
                        <input type="submit" value="Add / Save" />

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
                    </td class="input">
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

On submitting the text above i get the following error :

> Not Found The requested URL
>   /cms/events/add.php was not found on
>   this server.
>
> Apache/1.3.41 Server at
>   www.xyzs.in Port 80

Is this a problem with the text-encoding?

Comment: The path `www.xyzs.in/cms/events/add.php` is the correct script path?

Comment: Well the code snippet you provided, submitted to a page that does no processing causes no error. I'm going to go out on a limb here, does the site/cms use a .htaccess file to perform rewrites or redirects? What about load balancing, is this hosted on a single server or a pool of servers? (is add.php on all servers)

Comment: @Leigh I'm not aware if the server uses a .htaccess file to perform rewrites or redirects. Is there a way to find out? And no, this site is hosted on a single server.

Comment: Well there will be a file called `.htaccess` :) I just read the actual text you're trying to submit properly. What happens if you remove all occurrences of the word META?

Comment: @Leigh, i checked the contents of `.htaccess` - it is empty except for one php `include_path` specification. Also, i tried removing all occurrences of "META", but it didn't work.

Comment: Well, I'm a little lost for ideas now, without going for a trial and error approach to find out at what point the error starts occuring. If you shorten this text is it allowed? Is a different text of the same length allowed? At what point or at what word does it start breaking?

Comment: To check if its some part of the text that is causeing this, try to split the text in half and for each half replace the missing part with someting very simple, like all A's, if ony one part is causing the error repeat untill you find the char or word to change where it works. If no part works, well, then you got some very very strange errors ;)

Answer (score 0):

Could the add.php page contain an execute, maybe for an error page if the input is to long and the 404 is because the error page is not there?

I have seen similar errors in ASP where execute "" was used to load another page and if that page was not found you got an error, but exactly which error can differ from server implementation.

Also, does this work with other input with shorter or same length?

Comment: No, add.php does not cause the 404. Infact, it has nothing to do with this error. I checked by using the page to only print POST data (commented out all other script). It never reaches add.php. Also, I've tried random texts larger / smaller / equal to the length of this text and they work. It seems to be the content of the text causing this problem.

Comment: Have you tried to post with a simpler form containing only the textarea and a submit button and then add other fields and funtions one and one until you recreate the error?

Comment: yes. This is definitely a problem with the <textarea> and the text going into it.

Answer (score 0):

**For someone else with Similar Issue:**

Your text contains sensitive `keywords` which cause `404`. Last night I got similar issue with text area, After deep analyzing I found that my text contains a keyword "**Select**", When I remove it submits successfully. In your case keyword "**META**" might causing this error.

What you have to do is white list these sensitive `keywords` from your `server` by contacting your `server` `administrator`.